# hyperlink tag "<a>" not working in html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code in my html page:

```
    <body>
    <div align="center">
      <a href="../index.html">
      <img border="0" src="banner1.jpg" width="800" height="120" alt="Ecommerce Knowledge Base">    </a>

      <div style="background-image:url(Heading%20Background.jpg); width:800px">
      <a href="../index.html" style="position:relative; left:-130px">HOME</a>
      <a href="" style="position:relative; left:-65px" id="planning">PLANNING</a>   
    </div>
    ...
    ...
    ...
    </body>
```

The hyperlink `HOME` is linked to `index.html` page which is located in the root folder of the folder containg this html page. But nothing happens once clicking this hyperlink. Even the `banner` which is linked to the same page doesn't work.

The strange thing is, both these hyperlinks were working fine before, till I made some "jquery" code changes in my page. But I'm not sure how the change is affecting this. Kindly help.
These are the code changes made from:

```
    <script> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#planning").click(function(e){
        $("#planning_panel").slideToggle("slow");
        e.preventDefault()
       });
     });
    </script>
```

to:

```
    <script> 
    $(document).ready(function() {
     $(document).on('click',function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
   var $panel = $("#planning_panel");
   if (e.target.id === 'planning') {
     $panel.slideToggle('slow');
   } else {
     $panel.slideUp('slow');
   }

        });
      });
     </script>
```

Both the scripts are working fine, the only problem is as soon the changes were made the hyperlinks stopped working.

Comment: this seems working : http://jsfiddle.net/ceyrq/1/

Comment: @Jai: Not if you click the `HOME` link.

Comment: @TJCrowder if you click on the planning and then you click the Home link that will slide it up.

Comment: @Jai: The point is that the `HOME` link should actually work (take you to `../index.html`).

Comment: @TJ Crowder then i think Bastian Rang's answer should do the work.

Comment: @Jai: No, because that destroys the slidedown/slideup logic.

Comment: @TJ Crowder Perfect sir, Today i learnt a new chapter here. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This new code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click',function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     // ...
   });
});
```

...tells the browser that when a click occurs that bubbles up to the document (as most clicks eventually do, unless you call `stopPropagation` from a handler deeper down), the browser should *prevent the default action*. The default action of a click on a link is to follow the link.

The solution is to only call `e.preventDefault();` when you want to prevent the action of the click. Here's how I'd probably recast that code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click',function(e) {
    var $panel = $("#planning_panel");
    if ($(e.target).closest("#planning")[0]) {
      // Click is on the planning link, toggle the panel and prevent the default
      $panel.slideToggle('slow');
      e.preventDefault();
    } else {
      // Not on the planning link, slide the panel up
      $panel.slideUp('slow');
    }
  });
});
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/owiqis/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/owiqis/1/edit) *(I've changed `../index.html` to `http://stackoverflow.com` on the `HOME` link, but other than that the only change is the code)*

There we're only preventing the default action of the click if it's on the `#planning` link.

Side note: I've used [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) instead of checking `e.target.id` because it's more robust. It's not strictly necessary with your markup, but if you ever changed the markup *slightly* (adding a `span` or `em` or something), you'd need it, so it's good for robustness.

Comment: @Siddharth: `$(e.target).closest("#planning")` starts with `e.target` and sees if it matches the selector. If it doesn't, it looks `e.target`'s parent element, and then *its* parent, etc. We end up with an empty jQuery set if the click wasn't anywhere on the planning link, or a set containing the planning link if it was. Then we use `[0]` (get the first raw element in the set) to see whether the set has anything in it. (We could also have used `.length`.)

Comment: Sir, still one problem, if I recast the code like this. The panel is not at all toggling in the first place, when I click on the `planning` link. Can you throw some light, what again could be causing this ?. Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: @Siddharth: It does in my live example...?

Comment: Crowder: Very sorry Sir, the error was due to my JQuery Library file not been copied properly to the right path.My bad... The code is working perfect now. Thanks again for your prompt replies

Comment: @Siddharth: Ah, good, glad it was something easy to sort out. Best,

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on('click',function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
```

It will prevent any click default behavior.

Answer (score 1):

This should be the problem:

```
$(document).on('click',function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
```

you prevent all clicks on document, so the links cannot function properly. change the first of the lines to

```
$('#planning').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
```

by the way: i don't really understand what your function does.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on('click',function(e) {
```

this should be like,

```
$(document).on('click', '#planning', function (e) {
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(document).on('click',function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var $panel = $("#planning_panel");
if (e.target.id == 'planning') {
 $panel.slideToggle('slow');
} else {
 $panel.slideUp('slow');
}

    });
  });
```

use this mate

Comment: the problem isn't the triple '=', it's the preventDefault on the document-click-event.